# fql not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have used a fql for get my friends information

```
SELECT uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,pic_square,hometown_location,current_location,profile_url,email,website FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

it returning only friends id an name. Who have trusted my app there location also comming but when I am puting this fql on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,pic_square,hometown_location,current_location,profile_url,email,website%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29)
on facebook then it returns every one's location. Then How Can I get every one's location ?

Comment: That is incomprehensible. Please check what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to understand your question, though it looks like your app doesn't have all the required user permissions. The Graph API explorer, or the developer page are great resources to figure out which ones you need.

Hometown location,current location, email, and website are not "basic" data.